# How do I serialize a class with Django and non-Django properties for Json ajax output?

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, serialization

Lets say have this object:

```
class Zoo:
    def __init__(self, animal):
        self.animal = animal # a Django Model Animal object
        self.list_of_sounds = [] # type: list[a Django Model Sound Object]
        self.add_sounds()

    def add_sounds(self):
        for id in list(range(0, 5)):
            AnimalSound(animal_id=id, noise='woof')
            self.list_of_sounds.append(AnimalSound)



animal = Animal.objects.filter(pk=1).first()
zoo = Zoo(animal)
json_to_output_via_ajax = serializers.serialize('json', [zoo])
```

This throws an error:

```
{AttributeError}'Zoo' object has no attribute '_meta' because zoo has a the property list_of_sounds which is not a Django object.
```

What is the best way to send this object's JSON via ajax?

Comment: A JSON is merely a dictionary. Create a function that builds you a dictionary of the way you want the JSON to be sent. Call it `as_dict` or `to_dict`. It should return a dictionary. That is what you can send as JsonResponse. This way you don't need to serialize or anything.

I can show you an example in an answer but not sure it is needed.

Comment: This did the trick:

    def object_to_json(something):
        return json.dumps(something, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
def object_to_json(something):
    return json.dumps(something, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)
```